# Sequence number for COMMITTED concurrent inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction, concurrency, sequence

For example, I have a table

```
create table Queue (OrderNum int, Data varchar(1000)) --int - may be a different type
```

and many concurrent inserts into this table. Is there is a way to fill the `OrderNum` column with data that will show the order in which a row was **committed** in this table? ***Not* inserted**!

I want to realize many `Queue` readers, which will periodically select new rows where `OrderNum` > (`max(OrderNum)` of the previous select from `Queue`). In this case I can't use either `identity` or `rowversion`, because they are generated in the `INSERT` statement and the reader can select a committed row with `OrderNum = 2` while a row with `OrderNum = 1` still isn't committed. So we would have a gap, or data loss for readers.

Comment: A trigger + sequence?

Comment: @McNets But triggers work in transactions and `sequence` works same as `identity` and `rowversion` - generates during `insert + trigger` executing, and may finally committed in "wrong" order. Isn't it?

Comment: Generally, queue tables will either have a status, or remove records after they are processed, so that your query is more like `SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE Status = 'new' ORDER BY OrderNum` without having to actually filter on the order number to get new rows. Is there a reason you couldn't use a status column?

Comment: @AMtwo, yes. We need to process up to 1500 rows in second.

Comment: Processing 1500 rows/second doesn't preclude managing status for each item in the queue...

Comment: @AMtwo each reader must read each row. With no lost rows. In right order. We can achieve this using simple `read commited` locks, but we should avoid of readers wait on write side. Unfortunately, track read status of each row for each reader is too costly.

Comment: I think you'll find something for maintaining the ID in the way you describe may not meet those throughput/concurrency goals. If those are hard requirements, you may want to include them in your question

Comment: With sequences, you can fetch the value you plan to use before using and therefore not like identity or rowversion.